# Add part of the list to another list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to move part of the list to another list with a loop
But I have problem

Something like that (But this code is bug)

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

i=[]

for i in mylist.append(range(1,5)) :
    print(i)
```

I want the numbers 2 to 6 to be in i

---

Thanks to everyone I solved this problem
With this code

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

i = []
b=0
c=1
while b < 5 :
    i.append(mylist[c])
    print(i)
    b+=1
    c+=1
```

Comment: `append` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Please take a look at the duplicate post I've linked above - in particular the answer with the highest votes.  The typical way to do this is with `list.extend`, but if you want to append elements in a list one by one, you will need to modify your loop.  Have a look at the middle of the answer to show you how.

Comment: I used 'extend' but still have "'NoneType' object is not iterable" error and have no idea about it
I searched a bit but I didn't understand anything